# Cloning last row in ag grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am missing something, yet.. I have ad grid, and can't figure out, how to clone last row.

Here is snippet of what I try to do:

```js
lastrow = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(
  gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount() - 1
);
gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: [lastrow] });
```

optionally I tried:

```js
gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: lastrow });
```

but that doesn't work neither.

I am also unable to access cell value by column name, like

```js
window.alert(lastrow["1"])
```

"1" is valid field name.

What am I doing wrong?

I must also mention, that

```js
firstrow = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0);
gridOptions.api.setRowData(firstrow);
```

kinda works,but resets all rows, and I need to clone last row, not delete all rows, besides last.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So [based on docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#accessing-row-nodes), you are able to get `RowNode` by the index:

> **`getDisplayedRowAtIndex(index)`** Returns the displayed **rowNode** at the given index.

*keep in mind, it will return `RowNode` - not `RowNode.data`*

And to get the last index you just need to use another method:

> **`getLastDisplayedRow()`** Get the index of the last displayed row due to scrolling (includes not visible rendered rows in the buffer)

now once you know how to get `RowNode` you just need to execute `updateRowData` with **`node.data`**

*P.S. you need to use `RowNode.data` - instead of `RowNode` itself.*

Here is a code:

```
let lastrow = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(this.gridApi.getLastDisplayedRow());
this.gridApi.updateRowData({ add: [lastrow.data] });
```

And here is a [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VM3WMoSz8tVPGsf1bpKi?p=preview)

Comment: thats absolutely correct. just figured it out, run to answer own question, but you beat me to it. 
thanks, however

Answer (score 1):

There is a api method for getting the index of the last displayed row, 
can use that index to get the row.

```
lastRowIndex = gridOptions.api.getLastDisplayedRow();
lastRow = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(lastRowIndex);
```

Not sure if that accomplishes everything you are trying to do, but based off the question this will get the last displayed row.

Comment: no, thats not what I am asking for.

i can get last row.. or some row
>someRow=gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0);

i am unable to:
>gridOptions.api.updateRowData({add: [someRow]});

after